# Help finding out what Icon represents

Tags: icon

I'm just looking for some help finding out what the below icon represents?

[image]

Comment: Where does this icon come from ?

Comment: It was sent to me in a presentation but the owner of the presentation said it had been historically included and no one had questioned it before - it was included along with more standard social media icons if that's any help. Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to Apple Software/Hardware.

Comment: Ah yes my apologies on that - after combing the internet I then posted this question on a number of forums to spread the net wide as I thought it might be a system specific icon that was simply being incorrectly used in this case (e.g. some kind of app or software's icon rather than a social media icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse image searches with [tineye.com](http://tineye.com) and [Google Search by Image](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html) return no matches. This is not a widely used image with a common meaning.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I too had found this and so many thanks for confirming my findings - I think it might be some weird outdated wifi icon and so I will be removing it but thanks for looking. Cheers